# Negative regex match in Sublime Text 3 for removing unwanted code

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

```
... <tr class="GridRow_Business"> **[important info]** </tr> ...
```

How can I match everything **except** `[important info]`?

I tried:

```
(?!\{)Row_Business">(.*?)</tr>(?!\})
```

and similar variations of it, but with no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you want. Would replacing `(?s).*(<important info>).*` with `\1` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^<]*(<tr[^>]+Row_Business\">)([^<]+)(</tr>)
```

This matches everything in 3 groups.

- Group 1 matches the opening tag
- Group 2 matches anything between the opening and closing tag
- Group 3 matches the closing tag

You can therefore get what you need with `\1\3`

**EDIT**

Based on the refiddle example in the comment the regex is now:

```
(<tr[^>]+Row_Business\">)(?:[\n\t]*.*[\n\t]*)*?(</tr>)
```

This matches everything in 2 groups. The 2nd set of parentheses are now a non-capturing group and the `*?` after that group makes it non-greedy. Again, based on the provided refiddle example, using `\1\2\n\t` will return:

```
<tr class="GridRow_Business"></tr>
<tr class="GridAltRow_Business"></tr>
<tr class="GridRow_Business"></tr>
<tr class="GridAltRow_Business"></tr>
```

Comment: @overdriven It wouldn't because your refiddle example is multi-line. See the edited answer

Comment: @garyh you can tersify that RegEx even more by using [\s\S] in the non-capturing group. I also recommend escaping the forward-slash in the second capturing group: (<tr[^>]+Row_Business\">)(?:[\s\S]*?)(<\/tr>)